# Why is my Mesos master failing authentication with slave?

Tags: authentication, distributed-computing, mesos, mesosphere

I have created a master on my machine with a credentials file that has a public IP on the network rather than localhost as follows:

```
./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=192.168.0.3 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos --credentials=file://master-cred.json
```

I then created a slave on another machine as follows:

```
./bin/mesos-slave.sh --ip=192.168.0.19 --master=<master-ip>:5050 --credential=file://slave-cred.json
```

Then the master outputs an incoming authentication request however each time it gets refused:

```
I0903 15:17:48.264104 165863424 master.cpp:4728] Authenticating slave(1)@192.168.0.19:5051
I0903 15:17:48.264602 166936576 authenticator.cpp:92] Creating new server SASL connection
I0903 15:17:48.269961 165326848 authenticator.cpp:197] Received SASL authentication start
I0903 15:17:48.270058 165326848 authenticator.cpp:319] Authentication requires more steps
I0903 15:17:48.272733 166400000 authenticator.cpp:225] Received SASL authentication step
W0903 15:17:48.272817 166400000 authenticator.cpp:325] Authentication failure: authentication failure
W0903 15:17:48.273136 166400000 master.cpp:4755] Failed to authenticate slave(1)@192.168.0.19:5051: Refused authentication
```

Both the credential files are correct.

This is the output from the slave:

```
I0903 15:17:48.232733  2377 slave.cpp:747] Authenticating with master master@192.168.0.3:5050
I0903 15:17:48.232951  2377 slave.cpp:752] Using default CRAM-MD5 authenticatee
I0903 15:17:48.235091  2376 authenticatee.cpp:91] Initializing client SASL
I0903 15:17:48.239701  2376 authenticatee.cpp:115] Creating new client SASL connection
I0903 15:17:48.239914  2377 slave.cpp:720] Detecting new master
I0903 15:17:48.241755  2377 slave.cpp:4193] Received oversubscribable resources  from the resource estimator
I0903 15:17:48.287488  2378 authenticatee.cpp:206] Received SASL authentication mechanisms: CRAM-MD5
I0903 15:17:48.287619  2378 authenticatee.cpp:232] Attempting to authenticate with mechanism 'CRAM-MD5'
I0903 15:17:48.290863  2378 authenticatee.cpp:252] Received SASL authentication step
Master master@192.168.0.3:5050 refused authentication
```

However when I run the slave from the same machine as the master, it works fine. Any ideas?

Comment: When start mesos-master, try add `--authenticate --authenticate_slaves`

Comment: And does contents in master-cred.json and slave-cred.json are matched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually being caused by a problem with how I set up the networking on the virtual machine slave.